# Unable to checkin UserControl.xaml files in TFS. Receving error: TF10169

Tags: vb.net, xaml, tfs, desktop-application, checkin

Project Type in Visual Studio 2013 is Desktop Application. And I have added a user control in XAML format in that desktop application. I used some compatibility functions and libraries so that xaml control be able to integrated with simple desktop application.

TFS is checking In other related files, but when moved xaml files from 'excluded' section to 'included' section in tfs pending changes window and check In. TFS donot checkin any file and  give me following error:

**The following issues were encountered during check in: TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/Code. Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.**

Can any body help me out to figure out this issues and fix it. why XAML file are not able to checkin?

Comment: Does the folder $/Code exist in TFS? It might be that the Source Control Repository was destroyed: http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2011/07/06/removing-source-control-from-a-tfs-project.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had to go to my xxx.visualstudio.com url in my browser and use the "New" link under "Recent projects and teams" section to create a project there first.  Once I did that, my check in worked from my local visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

There are one of two issues:

1. You used to have a team project called "Code" that has been deleted but leaving the source history and you are trying to check in under it.
2. There is no such team project

You need to create a team project in TFS before you can check in code. All code must be checked in under an active team project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477.aspx

Use the link above to find out how to create your first team project.