# Is a TFS Workspace a middle ground between the project source and the server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfvc

Our team is in the process of putting our projects into TFS. I am trying to understand the concept of the Workspace. It creates one for me C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\

Then, if I understand it correctly, I am to copy the projects I want to have in TFS there. So, if I had a project named "Boomerang" I would copy it to C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\ so that I would have a folder there named C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\Boomerang

Okay, but do I now need to, when working with that project in Visual Studio, open the project from C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\Boomerang? IOW, my original location for it, say C:\Projects\Boomerang, now becomes a redundancy?

I doubt it, but it seems strange to me that I would make a change in C:\Projects\Boomerang, then check it in (to C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\Boomerang), because it's still all on my local machine. How does it then get from C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\Boomerang to the TFS server location, so that the team wold also have access to it?

If this is how it is - transfer from original location to local Workspace, how does it get from the local Workspace to the server?

ISTM that the whole process could be made much easier and more transparent by simply right-clicking a project in VS and selecting "Add to TFS" or some such. It could then prompt you for the particulars. Thereafter, just periodically check in changes and/or checkout changes (get latest). As it is now, it sure seems like it's more convoluted than it needs to be. Especially this copying of projects to the Workspaces location; if that's really how it's supposed to be done, it doesn't feel right to me...

Anyway, my main question is, once I have a project in the Workspace, do I need to open my project from there when working on it in VS? If so, what is the use of the files in the original location, except as a backup?

BTW, I read [this](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000333.html), but am still at least a little confused.

### UPDATE

I did go to the Solution Explorer in VS, and noted that there is, indeed, an "Add Solution to Source Control..." item that is available when right-clicking the solution.

However, when I attempted a checkin of the items, it failed ("See Output windows for details about the failed check-in. No files checked in").

The Output window says:

*TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil.  Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.*

### UPDATE 2

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379952/unable-to-checkin-usercontrol-xaml-files-in-tfs-receving-error-tf10169) about the err I got has been viewed almost one third of ten thousand times, so this is obviously not an obscure mixup.

### UPDATE 3

The screenshot below shows that my Workspace does have a CSReports folder, which I created in the Team Explorer pane, and also a RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil folder, which was added when I, from the VS Solution Explorer, selected "Add Solution to Source Control...":

[image]

Yet all seems mangled and frayed, as far as actually synching this folder with TFS goes.

Comment: You can't map a workspace to the root (`$/`). You have to map it within a Team Project. If you don't have any team projects, you'll have to create one.

Comment: I'll have to play with this more; I thought I did create, in the server I was pointed to, a project (CSReports), and then added the project to that. It's as if TFS claims to be speaking Spanish, whereas it's really jabbering away in Portuguese.

Comment: I do have a Team Project, which I created; it's called CSReports. I can see it when I got to Team Explorer > Settings > switch to the "Overview" tab on that page, and there it is: Collection profile => Name = Client Services; Projects => Project Name = "CSReports"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workspace is simply a mapping between a location in TFVC source control and a folder on your local machine. It says "the files located in $/Foo/Bar/ in source control are in C:\Source\Baz on this computer".

If you want the changes to be available for check-in, yes, you have to make them within the workspace folder.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have the same concern, too. If I make any changes to the project that open from my local directory which has been already mapped to TFS, does that affect the project on server? Or I could understand that it is a local copy for testing purpose before you commit the changes in source control?

Comment: @LONG You have to explicitly commit the changes. In TFVC, it's known as a "check-in".

Comment: cause before I use bit bucket source control. Can I still check in the changes if I open the local mapped project?

Comment: @DanielMann: So the original location of the project is now "dead" (at least as far as TFS is concerned)? If that's the case, I don't grok why they want to create a separate location (the users folder) to store the code that matters from the TFS perspective. I would prefer to keep the original location as the source to open in VS and edit and checkin from. Still seems bizarro to me...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Then change your workspace. A workspace can be mapped to any location you choose.

Comment: @DanielMann: I'm having a tough time acccepting this; it seems backward, to me. It would make more sense, IMO, to just say, "Make sure to back up your project before connecting it with source control." Now (give instructions for leaving the project in place and binding it to a TFS server). That way it's only in two places: one local, one cloudy with a chance of meatheads. Why orphanize the original local location for the project?